# How to reuse a variable, which is a reference to a hash?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to add a few hashes to the array, reusing the same variable (in my real program, I'm doing this in a loop, that's why reusing the var). This is the code:

```
my @items;
my %x;
$x{'aa'} = 'bb';
push(@items, \%x);
%x = (); # I think the error is here, I'm not resetting the reference :(
$x{'cc'} = 'dd';
push(@items, \%x);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@items;
```

However, what I see is not what I expect:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'cc' => 'dd'
          },
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];
```

What do I misunderstand?

ps. This is how it looks in the loop:

```
my @items;
my %x;
foreach ... {
  %x = ();
  $x{'aa'} = some_random_number();
  push(@items, \%x);
}
```

Comment: *"in my real program, I'm doing this in a loop"* : Can you include the loop in your code example to clarify? Also show the expected output

Answer (score 3):

Reusing a hash reference that way is not possible, it will always point to the same hash. And if you reset the same hash over and over and add new values to it, of course the beginning of the hash will be deleted.

You are correct that `%x = ()` is the problem, because that is where you delete the content in `%x` (the 'aa' key).

What you want is to create a new hash reference for each value you want to store.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @items = qw( .... );
foreach ... {
    my %x;       # use a lexically scoped variable, which will be new each iteration
    $x{'aa'} = some_random_number();
    push(@items, \%x);
}
```

Or even:

```
my %x = (aa => some_random());
```

Or better yet, use a hash reference right away

```
my $x = { aa => some_random() };
push @items, $x;
```

Or again, a bit quicker:

```
push @items, { aa => some_random() };
```

`{ ... }` creates an anonymous hash ref. Reusing variables is not a good idea, hardly ever. Unless you are using so many variables that you are afraid of memory issues. Use the lexical scope and anonymous references to your advantage to encapsulate your code and avoid confusion.

But since you are using different keys, and pushing them onto an array, I feel like you are confused about Perl data structures. You could just use the same hash, if your keys are different:

```perl
my %x;
foreach ... {
    $x{$key} = some_random_number();
}
```

You probably want a variable to keep track of the key name there, not a constant.

In the comments you describe a practice of adding values to the hash, and then adding it to the array to start over. This is exactly why you should use a lexically scoped hash. For example:

```perl
....
for my $table (@tables) {
    my %hash;       # <--- new variable for each $table
    for my $stuff (@stuff) {
        $hash{$stuff} = something();
    }
    ....
    push @array, \%hash;
}
```

If you put an enclosure around the hash, it will be reset automatically, and then use the "same" name space the following iterations, except it will point to a different memory location (a new data reference).

Or if, as you say, you cannot use a loop outside, you can just put a block around the variable.

```perl
{   # start of a block
    my %hash;
    for my $stuff (@stuff) {
        $hash{$stuff} = something();
    }
    ....
    push @array, \%hash;
}   # end of a block
    my %hash;   # this "%hash" is a different variable from the previous
```

Comment: Like I said earlier, I _do_ need to use the same variable name. My `$x` is filled with data and at some point I put this hash into the array. Then, I clean up the hash and collect new data into it. Again, when it's ready, I need to push this new hash into the array. The variable name must remain the same. Is it possible?

Comment: Basically, I have a hash, which is filled up with data. I add a reference to it into an array. Then, I want to modify my hash, but make sure that what is in the array remains untouched. Maybe I can make a copy of it somehow, before adding to the array?

Comment: It is possible to copy hashes, and it can be easy or hard, depending on your data structure. You may need a module for deep copying. What is at the heart of your question, though, is that reusing a hash variable is a bad idea, and it really is that you should change, and what your question should be about.

Comment: In other languages it's not a bad idea, while in Perl it is? (to the best of my knowledge, variables are invented in order to be reassigned, that's why they are called "variables" :)

Comment: If you want to talk about other programming languages, you'll have to ask someone else. But I seriously doubt that in other languages you can do what you do here without problems. If you explain why you think you have to have the same hash name, I can explain why that is not true.

Comment: And in every language it holds true that if you add values to a variable, and then delete it, that data is then gone. Which is what you are doing.

Comment: Think of the hash you are using as a container, a bucket. In this bucket you can store values, scalar values. The reference is the address to this bucket. It is not the address to the values themselves.

Comment: I understand this, but even if it's a reference, why calling `%x = ()` doesn't create a new place in memory ready to accept new data? Instead, it cleans up what the reference is pointing to... The assignment operator doesn't work like this in C/Java/PHP/Rust/Python.

Comment: I feel pretty sure that is not the case. I've added a solution that should work with whatever your code does now. If you use a lexically scoped variable, it will reset each new iteration, the way you intend.

Comment: Can you please update your answer keeping in mind that (as was mentioned in my question) `%x` must be declared outside of `foreach`? This is important, because it is modified not by a single loop cycle, but by a few of them, while only one of them adds it to the array, and then cleans it up.

Comment: That is what my latest addition suggests, that you declare the hash outside the inner loop, but inside some other form of enclosure that allows you to use a lexically scoped variable in order to reuse the name space (not the reference, but the name). A for/foreach loop (for and foreach are aliases to the same function in Perl) was just an example of a loop. It is hard to suggest what type of enclosure you should use since I do not know your code.

Comment: I have only one loop and I can't introduce another one, since this will break the algorithm. Anyway, looks like making a copy is the only option.

Comment: Well, in Perl you can do whatever you want. You can just put an empty block around the "old code", and then declare a new variable `%x` with a new name space. I will add an example.

Comment: Also, like I said earlier, if you explain why you think you need to use the same variable name, I can tell you why that is not true.

Comment: The solution is `%temp = %x; push(@items, \%temp);` --- works like a charm.

Comment: Or `push @items, { %x }` without using a temp variable. That is a bad solution in my book, though.